# get Item Index of arrayList knowing its Name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

is there a function that take array list item and bring back item index ?

for ex:

```
int indexItem = ArrayList.getItemIndexByName(itemName);
```

Comment: By name do you mean a field or property of the object as in `myObject.Name` or the variable name `nameOfObject = myObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single method that will give you this, but you could first search for your item by name, then use [ArrayList.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.indexof.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.indexof%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

```
int indexItem = myArray.IndexOf(itemName);
```

You can use it like this.

```
String itemName = "Hello";
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
myArray.Add( "Hello" );
myArray.Add( "World" );

// Get index of "Hello"
int indexItem = myArray.IndexOf(itemName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried storing your items in a `Dictionary<string, MyItemType>` ?